# How to provide attributes for fields for struct annotated with an attribute itself?

Tags: rust

I wanted to implement a `proc_macro_attribute` such that:

```
#[component]
struct Div {
    #[prop]
    color: String,
    clicked: bool
}
```

Where the impl of both the attributes are:

```
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn component(_attribute: TokenStream, input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    modify_struct_and_generate_props_struct(input)
}

// Just as a placeholder attribute for the component attribute to work on.
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn prop(_attribute: TokenStream, input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    input
}
```

I could do it with a custom derive, but that is not what I want to achieve here because any struct annotated with `#[component]` would be modified to include additional fields. The `#[prop]` sub attribute is used to create a newer struct made up of only prop fields.

The `proc_macro_attribute` does not support other sub-attributes used within its context and I tried to implement a separate attribute to mitigate that. This causes the compiler to error out with:

```
error[E0658]: The attribute `prop` is currently unknown to the compiler and may have meaning added to it in the future (see issue #29642)
  --> src/main.rs:33:1
   |
33 | #[component]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: add #![feature(custom_attribute)] to the crate attributes to enable
```

Adding this feature conflicts with `#![feature(proc_macro)]`.

I have defined the problem on [GitHub](https://github.com/csharad/proc_macro_attribute). You could look it up to see what I am trying to accomplish.

Is there no other possible way out?

I have also filed an [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49411) with Rust if this was not the way it was meant to be.

Comment: Procedural macros does not impact the structure because structures are already defined at the moment of proc-macro expansion. If this is not about your question, then I don't understand what do you mean by saying `I could to it with a custom derive, but that is not what I want to achieve here because any struct annotated with #[component] would be modified to include additional fields.`.

Comment: Procedural macros can modify/delete/reinterpret structures or any other language constructs as I have seen. But custom derive can only implement Traits but not alter the struct as far as I know. What I meant to convey was that the usage of custom derive could help me add custom attributes in field for me to process it but would not allow the struct's modification.

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes, I misunderstood this.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The proc_macro_attribute does not support other sub-attributes...

Actually it does.

The only thing is that, the compiler does not want any compiler unknown attributes on the final expanded struct. I was expanding the struct within the `#[component]` macro but leaving as-is the `#[prop]` attribute. This caused the compiler to search for meaning for the said macro and errored out.

So, to make it work, be sure to remove the attribute from the field after it has been used. Any residue will cause the compiler to error.

```
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn component(_attribute: TokenStream, input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let item: syn::Item = syn::parse(input).unwrap();
    let props_struct = generate_props_struct(&item);
    let modified_struct = modify_struct_and_remove_props_attribute(&item);
    quote! {
        #props_struct

        #modified_struct
    }
}
```

Also the struct does not require any placeholder attribute defined separately. Every attribute on the fields comes within the context of the `proc_macro_attribute` placed on the struct.

I have updated the [github repo](https://github.com/csharad/proc_macro_attribute) with comments to see how it could be done.